# Disqualification to hold US office for having "given aid or comfort to the enemies" of the United States

Tags: united-states, constitution, terrorism, michigan

[Section 3](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/amendment-14/section-3/) of the 14th Amendment to the US Constitution reads:

> No person shall be a Senator or Representative in Congress, or elector of President and Vice-President, or hold any office, civil or military, under the United States, or under any State, who, having previously taken an oath, as a member of Congress, or as an officer of the United States, or as a member of any State legislature, or as an executive or judicial officer of any State, to support the Constitution of the United States, shall have engaged in insurrection or rebellion against the same, or **given aid or comfort to the enemies thereof**. But Congress may by a vote of two-thirds of each House, remove such disability.

Could Representative Rashida Tlaib be disqualified from holding office due to her [false propaganda](https://katv.com/news/nation-world/squad-members-falsely-claim-israel-was-responsible-for-gaza-hospital-rocket-attack-rashida-tlaib-ilhan-omar-biden-israeli-palestine-war) in support of US-designated terrorist group [Palestinian Islamic Jihad](https://www.dni.gov/nctc/ftos/pij_fto.html#:%7E:text=The%20US%20Department%20of%20State,Designated%20Global%20Terrorist%20in%202014.)'s attack on the hospital and her [alleged connections to Hamas](https://www.jpost.com/international/islamic-terrorism/article-770179)?

The [Yale Law Journal](https://www.jstor.org/stable/787437) says:

> ...speeches or written or printed articles or editorials ... consisting of statements either true or false of existing or of claimed conditions or facts the knowledge of or belief in truth of which, by encouraging would
> tend to increase his [the enemy's] resistance, or by discouraging would tend to
> diminish the effective of the United States, would be sufficient foundation for a finding both of adherence to the enemy and of giving of
> aid and comfort.

However, that is just one opinion.  Does it take more concrete support for the enemy according to other opinions?

How would a citizen start the process to disqualify someone who provides aid or comfort to an enemy of the US?

Comment: *How would a citizen start the process to disqualify someone who provides aid or comfort to an enemy of the US?* Establish "standing" for the purpose of bringing suit in a court of law. How to establish standing is a question of [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/), not Politics.

Comment: Fortunately this is a well-answered legal question. Unfortunately this is not a legal forum.

Comment: Also it appears you have already decided what the answer is and are looking for something to support your view instead of trying to determine if what she said qualifies or not. With the last part of your question asking how to go about getting her disqualified it is clear you are looking for a specific answer.

Comment: @JoeW I think an answer that purely verbal aid and comfort to the enemy is not enough could be a correct answer, especially if someone cited to case-law.

Comment: There is already an answer stating that but that doesn't change the fact that your question is asking how to start the process for disqualifying her from the ballot which suggests that you want an answer that says it is disqualifying and not one that says otherwise.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  It seems on topic given [**What's going on with the effort to disqualify Trump in 2023 under the Constitution, Article 14, Clause 3**](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81217/whats-going-on-with-the-effort-to-disqualify-trump-in-2023-under-the-constituti).  And given the answers there, it might even be answerable as multiple entities have filed lawsuits aimed at disqualifying Donald Trump.  The process for disqualifying a Representative would likely differ, though.

Comment: @bharring legal questions are not off topic here if they are also questions about inner workings of governments.  Since the person in question is an elected member of the US Congress, and the question is about her qualifications to continue to run for re-elections, this is not off topic.

Comment: I would like to point out that the quoted Yale Law Journal article comes from a period in the history of USA where it was argued that, for example, conscientious objection is "of assistance to the military endeavors of the enemy".

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov yes, I'm hoping for newer and more authoritative decisions, and a distinction between the (aid OR comfort) language of the 14th amendment versus (adhering to the enemy AND aid AND comfort) language of the article 3.

Comment: As a purely grammar question, does "thereof" and "the same" not refer to the Constitution of the United States?

Comment: @DJohnM I think “enemies thereof” refers to enemies of the  United States, in parallel construction to “Constitution of”, but I could imagine it meaning what you say also.

Comment: @DJohnM the oath is “defend the Constitution of the United States against all enemies, foreign and domestic” , so maybe you’re right

Answer (score 8):

No.

Aid and Comfort have legal meaning. Arguments and propaganda in support of a cause is not "aid and comfort".

Arguing for a position, no matter how factually wrong or repugnant, is not a crime in the US. You have to take concrete steps furthering specific acts/goals, not just advocate them (a legal site can give you more detail).

Remember that even NAMBLA and KKK are legal organizations. You could even, legally, be a communist and still be a congressman at the height of the Red Scare. Nearly impossible to get elected that way (for good reason), but there is no legal litmus test for candidates' policies (for good reason).

(Note that "aid and comfort" is part of the definition of treason, too. It has been explored.)

Edit: https://definitions.uslegal.com/a/aid-and-comfort/

Comment: It seems you're on the right track, but are you saying that "adhering to their Enemies, giving them Aid and Comfort" of article 3 is that same as "given aid or comfort to the enemies" in article 14?  Is there any court decision that supports that?

Comment: @DavePhD Generally, we assume that when the same phrase appears multiple times in the same document, it has the same meaning in each instance, unless we have some specific reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: @A.R. but the phrases are different (aid OR comfort) versus (adhering to the enemy AND aid AND comfort).  Apparently the obligation of allegiance (adhering to the enemy) aspect has to be proven for treason as a separate element.

Comment: @DavePhD Unfortunately, the Supreme Court has not yet ruled on the meaning of "and" and "or," though we'll probably get a ruling within the next year as part of [_Pulsifer v. United States_](https://www.motherjones.com/crime-justice/2023/10/supreme-court-pulsifer-criminal-justice-drug-definitions/).

Comment: Regardless, the meaning of aid would be the same in both cases, so would comfort.

Comment: @DavePhD: that (whether the same phrase has the same meaning) is perhaps an interesting Q. You could make that a separate Q, either here or on Law SE. I suggest on the latter, because here law answers tend to be of a lower quality, in terms of details at least.

Comment: I hate answering in comments, but since this doesn't look likely to be reopened with the current phrasing... "“Giving aid and comfort” has generally been given a similar definition to “engaging,” to the extent that both can involve voluntarily acting in ways that support insurrection. For instance, in 1867 the House refused to seat John D. Young of Kentucky, finding that he had given aid and comfort by, among other things, sharing information that led to the capture of Union soldiers." https://www.pogo.org/reports/the-constitutions-disqualification-clause-can-be-enforced-today

Comment: @DavePhD: And "The following year, the House refused to seat John Young Brown of Kentucky, finding that he had given “aid and comfort” to the enemy by publicly suggesting that anyone who joined the Union Army should be “shot down in their tracks.”" So you're probably correct that in different venues the same words were given different interpretation.

Comment: @DavePhD: And I knew of this example, but not of the exact reason invoked then, but I see now that "The 1919 exclusion of Victor Berger from the House of Representatives also was based on purely expressive acts: The House refused to seat Berger after he was found guilty of Espionage Act violations for publishing statements espousing socialist opposition to U.S. involvement in World War I. The House took these statements as giving “aid and comfort” to enemies during the war."

Comment: @DavePhD: OTOH IDK of anyone disqualified for merely verbally supporting a movement classified as terrorist by the US gov't. Free speech standards in the US have generally become more liberal since WW1 and the red scare.

Comment: @DavePhD: Finally, I see that the 1918 Yale paper you've linked in the Q actually contained all these examples minus Berger, so I'm not sure what you were looking for, in addition.

Comment: OTOH Wikipedia tells us that Berger's espionage conviction was overturned in 1921, but him being excluded from the House for a while remained as such as *fait accompli*, not subject to judicial review. He was re-elected in 1924 though and the House didn't oppose his sitting *then*.

Comment: So, one might surmise that since then, in practice, a conviction in court of espionage because somewhat associated with the House deeming it 'aid and comfort', even if technically speaking the House can still enforce that standard differently.

Comment: It should be noted that the house rejected a motion to censure her over the statements which should shed light on how they are viewed in regards to giving comfort and aid to the enemy. https://apnews.com/article/congress-house-censure-resolution-greene-tlaib-48d109c21c11f8df80053d15ff7b77b7

Comment: @JoeW the resolution would have accused her of "leading an insurrection", I would have vote "no" also

Comment: @JoeW now they took out the objectionable "leading an insurrection" part and censured her for legitimate reasons is a bipartisan manner.

Comment: @DavePhD Though you still had members on both side objecting to it on free speech grounds. And it should be remembered that the person who originally filed it has made a lot of statements that could be censured as well. https://www.poynter.org/commentary/2023/jake-tapper-gives-blistering-commentary-about-marjorie-taylor-greene/

Comment: @JoeW I don't support Greene or Trump.  People should support Ukraine, Israel and domestic production.  McCormick introduced the censure resolution that was passed.